# How to avoid indenting after a line that starts with a number?

Tags: indentation, formatting

I use Vim to write longer sequences of body text. It does automatic formatting, which generally works nicely. If I have a sentence that ends in a number, say a date or a year, and that number happens to be placed at the beginning of a line, Vim will indent the next line, as if it is part of a numbered list.

I am editing an `.rst` file.

I have looked at `formatoptions` and suspected the `n` flag of being the problem, but `set fo-=n` made no difference.

I think I am missing some obvious setting that could solve this, but I am unsure where to start looking. Obviously I looked at `formatoptions`, `fo-table`, `autoindent` et. al., but as I see it I already unset the relevant option. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the rst filetype has some custom indentation rules which 
add this indentation. This works by setting the `indentexpr` setting to `GetRSTIndent` in `/usr/share/vim/vim80/indent/rst.vim`.

To completely disable the rst indentation you can use something like:

```
augroup ftype_rst
    autocmd!
    autocmd Filetype rst setlocal indentexpr=
augroup end
```

This will disable *all* indent rules, which may not be what you want. To disable just these rules you can override the `GetRSTIndent()` function in `~/.vim/after/indent/rst.vim` (I've commented out the five lines that add indentation for lists):

```
let s:itemization_pattern = '^\s*[-*+]\s'
let s:enumeration_pattern = '^\s*\%(\d\+\|#\)\.\s\+'

function! GetRSTIndent()
  let lnum = prevnonblank(v:lnum - 1)
  if lnum == 0
    return 0
  endif

  let ind = indent(lnum)
  let line = getline(lnum)

  " if line =~ s:itemization_pattern
  "   let ind += 2
  " elseif line =~ s:enumeration_pattern
  "   let ind += matchend(line, s:enumeration_pattern)
  " endif

  let line = getline(v:lnum - 1)

  " Indent :FIELD: lines.  Don’t match if there is no text after the field or
  " if the text ends with a sent-ender.
   if line =~ '^:.\+:\s\{-1,\}\S.\+[^.!?:]$'
     return matchend(line, '^:.\{-1,}:\s\+')
   endif

  if line =~ '^\s*$'
    execute lnum
    call search('^\s*\%([-*+]\s\|\%(\d\+\|#\)\.\s\|\.\.\|$\)', 'bW')
    let line = getline('.')
    if line =~ s:itemization_pattern
      let ind -= 2
    elseif line =~ s:enumeration_pattern
      let ind -= matchend(line, s:enumeration_pattern)
    elseif line =~ '^\s*\.\.'
      let ind -= 3
    endif
  endif

  return ind
endfunction
```

You can also look at tweaking the `s:enumeration_pattern` regexp. You didn't really mention which cases fail for you, so I can't really help you there.

Comment: Thanks @Carpetsmoker. I'll give these options a go later, and let you know how it goes.

Comment: The `s:enumeration_pattern` was indeed the problem here. I've disabled it for now, but I'll look into tweaking it instead. Thanks for your input, @Carpetsmoker. Appreciated.

Comment: A final note on this. The tweak is actually very simple: `s:enumeration_pattern` now starts with `^\s+` instead of `^\s*`. Then if I want a numbered list, I need to start with at least one whitespace character on that line to trigger the automatic indentation, but I always do that anyway. This way it doesn't foul my normal flow, though.