# Why does the "rst" filetype automatically indent subsequent list items?

Tags: indentation, filetype

I've been having trouble understanding the behavior defined in `GetRSTIndent()` in `indent/rst.vim`. I'm specifically using Neovim v0.2.2, but I believe this file has not changed between Vim/Neovim.

### Background and Behavior

The specific indent file I'm referring to is on the Neovim GitHub repo [at this location](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/946c2a8ee85830c543e389724575ae531e89b170/runtime/indent/rst.vim).

The effect is as follows:

If I'm typing a list (numbered or bullet point), my indentation always carries over from the previous line, causing too much indentation. For example:

```
- First item<Enter>
  | <-- Cursor here.

- Item one<Enter>
  - Item two<Enter>
    - Item three

1. This is list item one<Enter>
   2. This is list item two<Enter>
         3. This is three<Enter>
                     4. This is four<Enter>
                                             5. This is five
```

In other words, for me to continue with my list with a new bullet point, I have to press `<Backspace>` or `<C-D>` to get back to the correct indentation level before typing my next item. (The situation is even more strange with numbered lists; I expect this is a bug.)

I checked on the `"markdown"` filetype and it does not have any of this strange indent behavior. In my opinion, the handling of the Markdown is as I would expect, but the handling of reStructuredText is counterintuitive (and, at least for me, a hassle).

### Question

My question is two part:

- Why might this behavior be explicitly hardcoded for the `rst` filetype?
- Can anyone see a reason why I shouldn't submit this as a GitHub issue for the `indent/rst.vim` file?

If this is this simply undesired/counterintuitive behavior, I'd like to open an issue on the GitHub repo. I just want to make sure I understand the issue clearly. At this point, I know "what" the indent file is doing, but I don't understand "why." The code seems redundant to features (i.e. `':set formatoptions+=n'`) already present in Vim.

### Workarounds for Present

For anyone who stumbles on this simply trying to fix the issue, here is how I have been able to do so at present:

Use `:set indentexpr=""` to avoid the behavior when editing reStructuredText (or edit the `indent/rst.vim` file directly to avoid using `GetRSTIndent()`)

If desired, the same affect can be obtained using `:set formatoptions+=n`. This also has the benefit of *only* wrapping when the line wraps automatically according to `'textwidth'` (Instead, the `GetRSTIndent()` increases indent every time you press `<Enter>` to start a new item--almost certainly not what you want!)

For further ideas on how to handle RST indentation, please also see this question: [How to avoid indenting after a line that starts with a number?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/12687/17423)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My hunch is that the author of the plugin always includes a blank line between their list items. Note that if you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> a second time, without first entering any further text, the cursor moves back out to the indent level of the list item.

According to [the spec](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#bullet-lists), this blank line is optional (although none of the examples in the [primer](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickstart.html#lists) omit it), so I think you can probably report this as a bug. (You should perhaps first check whether adding an issue to the GitHub repo is the mechanism for doing so that the Neovim maintainers favour: for Vim I believe it's suggested you should contact the plugin author directly, initially.)

I guess I can see some utility in the current implementation: if you're willing to always include the extra vertical spacing, it allows you to either create a sublist (by typing a new bullet point) or not (by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> and *then* adding the bullet) without having to adjust indentation manually at all.